# XIB TableViewCell not resizing to fit width

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I have created an XIB TableViewCell and was wondering what are the possible ways I can get it to fit the smaller screen rather than being cut off as shown below. In the large screens, the cell isn't being shrunk or widened to fit the screen size width accordingly

[image: Emulator view]

[image: UI element hierarchy]

Comment: do you set `contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`in your xib file?

Comment: No, it was Aspect Fill in my IB for this XIB. However, I tried aspect fill, scale to fill and neither changed the look

Comment: Do you have constraints that are pushing your UI elements too far to the right? Use `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect the frames and constraints art run-time. If that doesn't help, show the constraints you are using ... maybe even post the source to your XIB file.

Comment: @DonMag Here is the source of my XIB: https://pastebin.com/evFr5v1A

Comment: @btrballin - you have a number of conflicting / illogical constraints which is almost certainly what's causing the issue. I'd suggest you remove all constraints, and add them back one-by-one. Start as simple as possible, and make sure you have a clean "constraint chain" both vertically and horizontally. End of my day here, but I should be able to clean it up for you in the morning if you're still having issues (I'm on U.S. Eastern Time)

Comment: If you can do that, that would be awesome. I tried that approach to clean and start fresh but what ended up happening was that the cells wouldn't even display on my emulator. I needed specific sizing and margins for my elements and it was difficult to go one by one while maintaining those margins and sizes

Comment: I tried one by one and resolved any errors it threw at me, but still not able to achieve the auto layout re-sizing. It should scale the elements diagonally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying various changes to your XIB file - without success - I'm guessing there is some sort of conflict I can't see, or there is one or more corrupt (?) elements in the XIB source. Rather frustrating.

I started from scratch, though, and I believe I have a working version for you. Here are the results I can get...

On iPhone 8:

[image]

and on iPhone 5s (considerably narrower):

[image]

The source - including controller and associated classes with `IBOutlet` connections so you can run it - can be found here: https://github.com/DonMag/AnotherXIBCell

You will still have some adjustments to make... images, obviously... and you probably want some slight changes in spacing.

In addition, you probably want to tweak the layout for the middle section "bar" widths and spacing... it doesn't look so good when running on a wider device, or, for example, in landscape orientation:

[image]

But --- this will hopefully get you going.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I managed to resolve it by selecting all things in the auto-resizing. Granted, it was a different version of my XIB than what I shared with you (older version)